# Efficiency of loop vs if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, time-complexity

I have a use case where I want see if a set of data matches a very small list of conditions (for the sake of argument, let's say it's less than 20).

I'm executing JavaScript on both the client and server-side (NodeJS). I'm trying to choose between two options (or any others you may have) and am not sure how different the complexity and computation times would be. I have a feeling they're negligible.

**Option 1: Iterate list of conditions**

```
var conditions = [{
  prop: 'a', check: '===', val: 'foo'
}, { 
  prop: 'b', check: '!==', val: 'bar'
}];

for (var i=0;i<conditions.length;i++) {
  // Check conditions[i]
  if (conditions[i].check === '===') {
    if (data[conditions[i].prop] === conditions[i].val) {
      // Keep checking
    } else {
      // Fail
    }
  } else if (conditions[i].check === '!==') {
    ...
  }
}
```

**Option 2: Convert conditions into JavaScript**

```
if (data.a === 'foo' && data.b !== 'bar' && ... ) {
  // Passes
}
```

Option 1 executes in O(n) while Option 2 is O(1), technically, but does it really matter with such a small list, especially when you consider the time it would take to do a `JSON.eval()` and or serve up unique code for the account?

Comment: Profile it. Everything else is voodoo optimisation.

Comment: Perhaps, you shouldn't try to invent an expression language based on object properties. Instead just use generic functions to handle the already defined operators in JavaScript.

Comment: It seems I may not have given enough of a use case. `conditions` is a list of conditions that's provided by the user, so I need a way of evaluating data based on unknown input. I'm experimented with Javascript compiling, iterating a list, and even running user-defined functions on the database server. Trying to find a solution that's both efficient and scalable to thousand of clients (custom `condition` arrays).

Answer (score 2):

First of all `eval` is **bad** (most times).

The code looks ugly with all these if conditions but performance wise the code in them won't run if the condition isn't met. So eventually it takes a bit longer to parse but not to run it.

If your iteration count is that low, performance when using the first example shouldn't be a problem.

When you want exact measurements of time usage you could just write a test.

Answer (score 2):

In general, "compiling" your list of conditions is going to be considerably faster than "interpreting" them, if that really matters; you need to benchmark to find out whether it does. You could "compile" using `eval`, or using the `Function` constructor. However, such an approach should be taken only if really needed, which should be a rare case.

But I am not sure why you are inventing this little language for checking; by "language", I mean the things of the form `{prop: 'a', check: '===', val: 'foo'}`. You have to write those things; then you have to "parse" them at run time; then you have to execute them at run-time. JavaScript already has a perfectly good way to encapsulate such bits of functionality; they are called "functions". Among other advantages, such functions can be optimized by the engine if called enough times.

A function-based approach to your problem would be to write:

```
var conditions = [
  data => data.a === 'foo',
  data => data.b !== 'bar'
];

for (var i=0;i<conditions.length;i++) {
  // Check conditions[i]
  if (conditions[i](data)) {
      // Keep checking
    } else {
      // Fail
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Or more colloquially

```
conditions.every(condition => condition(data))
```

No matter how you write this, the performance is basically `O(n)` in the number of conditions. The number of comparisons/tests being made does not change. The question is the speed of executing those tests, not the big O order.

Comment: `conditions` is a set of conditions defined by the user, so I'm not able to compile them as described.

Comment: The question is whether you mean "negligible" in relative or absolute terms. In relative terms, there would be a big difference. In absolute terms, probably not.